# R Sample selection basic question with nrow

Tags: r

I follow one tutorial to split ds into several with `sample` and it works fine. I just can't sleep without  understaning what is going on behind the scene with `ind` dataset like in sample below, does it know/remember about `mtcars` somehow, it's just single column integer.  I indicated in comment what I'm trying to get, how R knows which row in dataset marked 1 or 2 ??

Yes I did my Hwork on basic syntax but this probably is too simple)

```
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mtcars), replace= T, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
ind
tdata <- mtcars[ind==1,]  # select rows where ind = 1 ??!! but we don't have ind column in mtcars???
vdata <- mtcars[ind==2,]
```

Updated with my interpretation after help from Adam.

1. `ind`  -- independent stand alone ds with single column int. No any logical relationship to `mtcars`. I tested this creating it manually and it works OK.
2. then it works with logical vector, matching rownum from mtcars to ind. Something like: let check row #1 from mtcars matching (by rownum)  row #1 from ind has value 1 so ind==1 translated to True and raw selected.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So, in `sample()` statement you are creating 2 samples with index 1 and 2. Say you have 10 rows, you are initializing 1 & 2 to every row randomly. Next, you are subsetting data in `mtcars[ind==1,]` saying all the rows that contain 1 or sampled, the subset it. Likewise for `ind==2`. Now you can go and sleep.

Comment: @MIch28: (1) I believe you're understanding here is correct, but your description of it is technically wrong so I want to make sure. `ind` is a stand-alone *vector* that, *does* have a logical relationship to `mtcars`, but only because you told it to be just as long as `mtcars` is. It is not part of that data.frame or related in any other way. (2) No, this is incorrect. It is matching by TRUE and FALSE, not row number. `ind==1` creates a vector of TRUE and FALSE and only selects the rows from `mtcars` for the indices in `ind` that are TRUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) This statement is saying the following: "Randomly sample the numbers 1 and 2 for a total number of how many rows there are in `mtcars` (32) with replacement, and make is such that a 1 has an 80% chance of being selected and a 2 has a 20% chance of being selected.

```r
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mtcars), replace= T, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
```

(2) This line of code is subsetting `mtcars` to only those rows where your vector (ind) is a 1. The code `ind==1` is creating a logical vector (i.e., full of `TRUE` and `FALSE`) values. Wherever there is a 1, `ind==1` will be `TRUE`, otherwise it will be `FALSE`.

```r
tdata <- mtcars[ind==1,]
```

(3) This line of code is essentially doing the same thing as step 2, but for wherever there is a 2 in `ind`.

```r
vdata <- mtcars[ind==2,]
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I had problem with (2).Concept of Logical vector is clear but big vague for me, I will update my post with my interpretation. Appreciate if you can check how I get this.

Comment: Thanks non_Dave. Sure your explanation is right but no for my level. I don't think  <rows that contain 1 (in mtcars)> is right wording. ind and mtcars are independent. Tx again. Still need keep awake.

Answer (score 1):

your assumptions are correct, can simplify you code to keep on point:

```
   ind <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2)
   tdata <- mtcars[ind==1,]    ## tota32 rows in mtcars
```

Re.
< subsetting mtcars to only those rows where your vector (ind) is a 1> (c)
This sound strange but it's true: Select all from A where B=1,  where A and B are different objects without any relationship between them. it works for each row, though not required that A and B have same row numbers.

Comment: Sorry Mario, made -1 for your response by mistake, thanks again.

Comment: Disagree with *"it works for each row, though not required that A and B have same row numbers."* In R the logical `ind==1` will recycle until its length is `nrow(mtcars)` which is almost never the intended behavior. Check output for -`mtcars[c(1,1,0) == 1, ]`.

Comment: Sorry @Shree, is this about first part <it works for each row> ? or about <not required that A and B have same row numbers> ?  Or both?

Comment: @Mich28 the second part if you break it up that way i.e. *"<not required that A and B have same row numbers>"*.